# Installing Prerequisite apps for testing our app in firebase Test Lab

Tags: android, firebase, testing, firebase-test-lab

How can we have another apps installed in devices that is used in testing process( robotests , ...) , before starting testing our app?

I mean my app needs some other apps to be installed in the device to work completely and correctly .

Is it possible?

i'm using firebase test lab

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot upload additional APKs via the Firebase web console, but you can interact with Test Lab by using the [gcloud command-line app](https://firebase.google.com/docs/test-lab/android/command-line) too.

The "beta" version of the gcloud command-line has an option to add additional APKs. If you run

`gcloud beta firebase test android run --help`

You will find the following option that allows you to install more apks:

```
 --additional-apks=APK,[APK,...]
    A list of up to 100 additional APKs to install, in addition to those
    being directly tested. The path may be in the local filesystem or in
    Google Cloud Storage using gs:// notation.
```

Here's an example on how you would use this to start a test:

```
gcloud beta firebase test android run \
    --app=build/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk \
    --test=build/outputs/apk/androidTest/debug/app-debug-androidTest.apk \
    --device model=walleye,version=28 \
    --additional-apks=path/to/another.apk
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, and could you explain more that how I can use this command? I mean where I should use this? sorry I'm new to this !

Comment: @HosseinYazdanfar you'd need to install `gcloud` SDK (preferably the standalone version): https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/downloads-interactive and then install component `beta`.

Comment: @HosseinYazdanfar I updated my answer and also added a link to the official documentation explaining how to use gcloud.

Comment: thanks,when I use this command: gcloud firebase test android run --type robo  --app=my apps\sample-bazaar-release.apk  --device model=Nexus6,version=21,locale=en,orientation=portrait  --additional-apks=my apps\bazaar.apk     then this result is shown:ERROR: (gcloud.firebase.test.android.run) unrecognized arguments:
  --additional-apks=my
  apps\bazaar.apk
  To search the help text of gcloud commands, run:
  gcloud help -- SEARCH_TERMS

Comment: Your example is missing "beta" as the 1st argument. Also make sure you have the latest gcloud version.